# Program stop working: System.IO.__Error.WinIOError

Tags: c#, windows, kernel-module

I don't have great experience in C# and handled services in MS but I have a peace of code that is called many times inside a bigger process:

```
private static void InvokeRTF2HTMLParseApplication(string rtfFileName, string htmlFinalFileName)
{
    string strRTFParseApplicationPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "rtfParse2Xhtml.exe";
    if (File.Exists(strRTFParseApplicationPath))
    {

        try
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = strRTFParseApplicationPath;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + rtfFileName + "\"" + " " + "\"" + htmlFinalFileName + "\"";
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("\\log.txt"))
            {
                Log(e.ToString(), w);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This calls a `rtfParse2Xhtml.exe`file to parse a rft and save as html file.
Randomly (And I can confirm that) sometimes I get the next error message:
[image]

And the process stops in `process.Start()` line, and breaks.
This is my event log message error:

```
Application: rtfParse2Xhtml.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.IOException
Stack:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, Int32, Boolean, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, System.String, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess)
   at EmpRtf2Xhtml.rtfParseInput..ctor(System.String)
   at EmpRtf2Xhtml.rtfParse2Xhtml.Main(System.String[])
```

In command line I call the conversion process using the `rtfParse2Xhtml.exe` and using the same `rtf` file when the program stops and everything works fine. So, I think isn't a strange char or symbol in the `rtf` file that prevents the conversion.

I also think that isn't folder permissions because this occurs always on the same folders, multiple times and not with the same test case.
This occurs in Windows 7 machine and in a Windows Server 2012R2.

My `rtfParse2Xhtml` code is this:

```
if (File.Exists(args[1]))
{
    Console.WriteLine("RtfParser: Update Files " + args[1] + ".");
}
string fileName= args[0];
string fileName2 = args[1];
rtfParse2Xhtml.fInput = new rtfParseInput(fileName);
rtfParse2Xhtml.fOutput = new rtfParseOutput(fileName2, false, Encoding.GetEncoding(28591));
Console.WriteLine("RtfParser: Start");
int num = rtfParse2Xhtml.TrataGeral();
Console.WriteLine("".PadRight(70, '-'));
Console.WriteLine("RtfParser: Stop with RC=" + num);
result = num;
```

The `rtfParseInput` constructor class:

```
public rtfParseInput(string fileName)
{
    this.fileInput = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
}
```

Comment: Are you always parsing the same file? Maybe the exception is thrown because you try to read from a file while it is already open in another process

Comment: In your `rtfParseInput` constructor, wrap the call to the `FileStream` constructor in a try-catch block and log the exception. Important for troubleshooting this issue are the exception message and the error code.

Comment: does rtfparse3xhtml actually work concurrently?

Comment: @zockDoc: No. I have a massive group of files to parse. Each one are have a name constructed like this: `"rtfTemp_" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Ticks + ".rtf"` So, it's almost impossible to open the same file. This is a Open - Parse - Close process.

Comment: @BugFinder: rtfparse3xhtml??? Did you mean rtfparse2xhtml? Yes... It works.

Comment: Im not saying it doesnt, it just may not work well if 2, 10, 20 copies are running.. the input file, are you sure its not in use? maybe by the av on the server (they like to hold things open) etc..

Comment: @milheiros For now you should do what Dork Vollmar said, and show us the exact exception message